# Calculate Ratios in columns, based on other columns

Tags: r

I am facing an thinking & programming problem. See below my question, I have no clue what a proper approach is (played with DPLYR's group_by, but without results). Many thanks in advance for trying helping me out here!

I have a data set like this:

```
Numbers   Area      Cluster  
1         A          1            
0.8       A          1
0.78      A          1
0.7       B          1
0.4       A          2
0         C          1
```

I want to calculate two new columns:

1. Show the % of Area's occurring in a specific cluster (Column_Example_1)
2. Per Cluster, a new index of the column numbers (in a range from 1 - 0) (Column_example_2). The new ratio should be based on the column Numbers #note: in the example it is just an example, it could also done differently, but we I want to make sure that the column Numbers is leading)

The result should be like this:

```
Numbers   Area      Cluster  Example_1                             Example_2 
1         A          1          60%  #5x cluster 1, and 3x Area A)   1
0.8       A          1          60%                                  0.8  
0.78      A          1          60%                                  0.78
0.7       B          1          20%                                  0.7 
0.4       A          2         100%                                  1
0         C          1          20%                                  0
```

Comment: Can you explain how you arrive at Example_2?

Comment: `df %>%
  group_by(Cluster) %>% 
  mutate(Example_2 = ifelse(row_number()==1, 1, Numbers))` ?

Comment: Hi @erocoar; yes, in this example it was to show the sequence of a specific cluster, based on the column numbers. (So if numbers is between 1 - 0, I want to have something similar for each cluster (so the highest value of a specific cluster should have a 1, the lowest should have a 0, and the rest between those two numbers, based on their number score of course). Sorry, hope that this explanation make sense for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to keep all rows, you can calculate the relative frequencies as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(numbers = c(1, .8, .78, .7, .4, 0),
                 area = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "C"),
                 cluster = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1))

df %>% 
  group_by(cluster) %>%
  mutate(example_1 = n()) %>%
  group_by(area, cluster) %>%
  mutate(example_1 = n() / example_1)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   area, cluster [4]
  numbers area  cluster example_1
    <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>     <dbl>
1    1    A           1       0.6
2    0.8  A           1       0.6
3    0.78 A           1       0.6
4    0.7  B           1       0.2
5    0.4  A           2       1  
6    0    C           1       0.2
```

Comment: Thanks! The column Example_1 totally works! Do you also know how I can make the example_2 column with your dplyr approach? Really appreciated!!

Comment: This will do the trick. Thanks! 
library(scales)
test <- test %>%
  group_by(cluster) %>%
  mutate(example_2 = rescale(numbers ))

Answer (score 1):

You can also do with `data.table`:

```
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(Numbers = c(1, .8, .78, .7, .4, 0), 
           Area = c(rep("A", 3), "B", "A", "C"), 
           Cluster = c(rep(1, 4), 2, 1))

df[, N := .N, by = c("Cluster")] %>% 
  .[, Example_1 := .N/N, by = c("Cluster", "Area")] %>% 
  .[, `:=`(N = NULL, Example_2 = Numbers)]
```

Output:

```
> df
   Numbers Area Cluster Example_1 Example_2
1:    1.00    A       1       0.6      1.00
2:    0.80    A       1       0.6      0.80
3:    0.78    A       1       0.6      0.78
4:    0.70    B       1       0.2      0.70
5:    0.40    A       2       1.0      0.40
6:    0.00    C       1       0.2      0.00
```